# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sound Design Stack Exchange](http://sound.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sound.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why Are Professional Sound Libraries So Noisy?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34268/why-are-professional-sound-libraries-so-noisy)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [A condenser mic gain tuning on a mixer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34324/a-condenser-mic-gain-tuning-on-a-mixer)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Add white noise to silence](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/33138/add-white-noise-to-silence)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Weird noises coming from EVERYWHERE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34264/weird-noises-coming-from-everywhere)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Filter Reverb and Echo at the time of recording in Audacity or any other software](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/33162/filter-reverb-and-echo-at-the-time-of-recording-in-audacity-or-any-other-softwar)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Beat detection and alignment](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/33152/beat-detection-and-alignment)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Permission and Legality for using others' sound design videos on my website](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34236/permission-and-legality-for-using-others-sound-design-videos-on-my-website)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Audio lags / drop-outs across the whole system (Windows 7 SP1)](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34197/audio-lags-drop-outs-across-the-whole-system-windows-7-sp1)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [When to apply noise reduction? Before or after other processing?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34332/when-to-apply-noise-reduction-before-or-after-other-processing)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Finding loud events in lengthy ambient recording?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34258/finding-loud-events-in-lengthy-ambient-recording)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the lot was IMO much better this time around!  That's great!

The main thing that jumped out at me was perhaps the titles.  Titles can be difficult, I know.  My general method is to start writing the question with a working title, and then when the question is written, reevaluate the title to make sure it's still appropriate for the finished question.

As the majority of the site traffic comes from google searches, it's imperative that the title be spot on, if the OP wants to get as many solid answers as possible.

As our users pop into the review queues, titles should be a focus.  I'll strive to do the same.